# Singular homology of the punctured plane.

Tags: homology-cohomology

If $\Delta = [a, b, c]$ is a triangle having the origin in its interior and $\Delta^{*} = [a, b, c] \setminus \{0\}$ is the same triangule with the origin removed. In topological space $X = \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$, does $\Delta^{*}$ have to be a simplex?

I believe so, because not being a simplex would mean that there is no continuous function $\sigma: \Delta_{2} \longrightarrow \Delta^{*}$, where

$$\Delta_{2} = \left\{\sum_{i=0}^{2} t_{i} \vec{e}_{i}: \ t_{i} \in [0, 1] \ and \ \sum_{i=0}^{2} t_{i} = 1 \right\},$$

is the standard 2-simplex. But it seems strange to me. Is this reasoning correct?

Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, $\Delta^*$ is not a simplex. One reason is that a simplex is compact but $\Delta^*$ is not compact.

Your concern about $\sigma_2$ is not an issue. Just because $\Delta^*$ is not a simplex does not mean there are no continuous maps $\sigma_2 : \Delta^2 \to \Delta^*$. There exist a lot of continuous maps like that, for example any constant map whose image is some point of $\Delta^*$.

What *doesn't* exist is a continuous surjective map $\sigma_2 : \Delta^2 \to \Delta^*$, because $\Delta^2$ is compact, $\sigma_2$ is continuous, the continuous image of a compact set is compact, but $\Delta^*$ is not compact.

Comment: No, $\Delta^*$ is not compact. The point $0$ is not an isolated point of the simplex $[a,b,c]$, meaning that one can construct a sequence of points $p_i \in [a,b,c] - \{0\}$ which converges to $0$. When you remove $0$ to get the subset $\Delta^* = [a,b,c]-\{0\}$, the sequence $(p_i)$ is in $\Delta^*$ but does not converge to anything in $\Delta^*$, in fact its subsequences all have nothing to converge to (because all of its subsequences converge to $0$ which has been removed). This proves that $\Delta^*$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Delta^*$ is not compact it can't be a continuous image of the compact space $\Delta_2$.

Comment: But isn't $\Delta^{*}$ compact in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Being compact is not a property of a subspace but of a space, it doesn't depend on any ambient embedding.

Comment: Ok, thank you, Christoph.